# Apache whitelist IP won't work with 2.4 .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2.4

I am trying to restrict a web directory to just one IP address.  Any other addresses will get routed to /updating.html

Here is my .htaccess config

```
# ALLOW USER BY IP
<Limit GET POST>
Require all denied
Require ip xxx.xxx.xxx
</Limit>

ErrorDocument 403 /updating.html 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now it routes everyone to /updating.html even my IP I have put in the Require ip.

I have googled whats my IP and put that one in.  Even checked if it was the correct one and also if I had any proxies open.  I have a wordpress installation in that directory but I keep getting directed to to /updating.

Comment: just because you reach one site with a particular ip doesn't mean you'll reach ALL sites with the same ip (e.g. ipv6 internally v.s. ipv4 externally). Check your server's access logs to see what IP really DID show up when you hit the site.

Comment: Thankyou, checking the apache logs revealed a different IP form the one I was getting!